# Problems resampling pandas time series with time gap between indices

Tags: python, pandas

I want to resample the pandas series

```
import pandas as pd
index_1 = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=4, freq='T')
index_2 = pd.date_range('1/2/2000', periods=3, freq='T')
series = pd.Series(range(4), index=index_1)
series=series.append(pd.Series(range(3), index=index_2))
print series
>>>2000-01-01 00:00:00    0
   2000-01-01 00:01:00    1
   2000-01-01 00:02:00    2
   2000-01-01 00:03:00    3
   2000-01-02 00:00:00    0
   2000-01-02 00:01:00    1
   2000-01-02 00:02:00    2
```

such that the resulting DataSeries only contains every second entry, i.e

```
  >>>2000-01-01 00:00:00    0
     2000-01-01 00:02:00    2
     2000-01-02 00:00:00    0
     2000-01-02 00:02:00    2
```

using the (poorly documented) resample method of pandas in the following way:

```
resampled_series = series.resample('2T', closed='right')
print resampled_series
```

I get

```
>>>1999-12-31 23:58:00    0.0
   2000-01-01 00:00:00    1.5
   2000-01-01 00:02:00    3.0
   2000-01-01 00:04:00    NaN
   2000-01-01 00:56:00    NaN
                  ...
   2000-01-01 23:54:00    NaN
   2000-01-01 23:56:00    NaN
   2000-01-01 23:58:00    0.0
   2000-01-02 00:00:00    1.5
   2000-01-02 00:02:00    3.0
```

Why does it start 2 minutes earlier than the original series? why does it contain all the time steps inbetween, which are not contained in the original series? How can I get my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resample()` is not the right function for your purpose.

try this:

```
series[series.index.minute % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what is resample actually for? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html does not give a very comprehensive answer. There are a few helpful examples, but most of the parameters and their possible values are not very well explained.

Comment: Here is the document: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#sparse-resampling